# How to check which button is ticked jquery/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quiet new to jquery and html. I'm facing an issue right now on how to save the value based on which button is ticked.

Scenario is:

1. I have a big `formregister.tpl` where one of the fields is `price`. This price is automatically computed and shown in the registration form which the user can manually change.
2. I have also `formregister.js` where the computation of the value for field price is done. Also, i have created a pop-up box `(dialogbox.tpl)` that pops when the value of automated calculation is different from what the user entered. This has 2 buttons which ask the user which one to save, the auto calculated value or the value he entered.

I don't want to pass value to `dialogbox.tpl` because the parent form already has the 2 values, so want to manipulate it from there.

Question:

> Is it possible to check from the `formregister.tpl` which button is ticked in the `dialogbox.tpl`?

I have searched the web already but unable to find similar scenarios.

Please let me know any related links that might help me.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your submit buttons a name and a value.

```
<input name="button1" type="submit" value="Button 1" />
<input name="button2" type="submit" value="Button 2" />
```

button1 or button2 will be passed via GET or POST.

Or you can do it with onclick

```
<input id="button1" 
       onclick="yourFunction(this);" 
       name="button1" 
       type="submit" 
       value="Button 1" />
<input id="button2" 
       onclick="yourFunction(this);" 
       name="button2" 
       type="submit" 
       value="Button 2" />
```

then you can check the ID in your function:

```
function yourFunction (button) {
    var yourButton = jQuery(button).attr('id');
}
```